# Intern on command line finds nodemailer but not a module required by it

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, require, intern

I'm cutting my teeth with intern and finding it rather hard going.  I've simplified my situation to a single `interntest` folder with a basic package.json and a single module, containing my intern.js and test module.

```
interntest/
    package.json
    src/
        mymodule/
            test/
                intern.js
                MyTest.js
```

My package.json lists the basic dependencies I need to run node in this directory:

```
{
  "name": "interntest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "intern": "1.3.2",
    "nedb": "~0.9.3",
    "nodemailer": "~0.5.14",
    "requirejs": "",
    "dojo": "1.9.2"
  }
}
```

`npm install` does now fetch these dependencies.

The immediate problem is with the `nedb` and `nodemailer` modules I'm trying to use.  I had thought I could simply declare them in intern.js like so:

```
loader: {
    // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
    packages: [
        'node', 
        'nedb',
        'nodemailer',
```

And required in MyTest.js simply with:

```
define([
    'intern!tdd',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'nedb',
    'nodemailer'
], function (test, assert, Datastore, nodemailer) {
```

But it seems `nedb` cannot be loaded, despite `node_modules/nedb/package.json` correctly specifying `main: 'index'`.

```
neek@alyssa:~/src/interntest$ ./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=src/mymodule/test/intern suites=mymodule/test/MyTest
Defaulting to "console" reporter
Error: Failed to load module nedb/main from /home/neek/src/interntest/node_modules/nedb/main.js (parent: mymodule/test/MyTest)
    at /home/neek/src/interntest/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:742:12
    at fs.js:207:20
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

To try to get around this, I end up having this in `MyTest.js`:

```
define([
    'intern!tdd',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'nedb/index',
    'nodemailer/lib/nodemailer'
```

This seems wrong but at least gets around the initial failure to load any .js files at all from those modules.  However, this seems fatally flawed:

```
neek@alyssa:~/src/interntest$ ./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=src/mymodule/test/intern suites=mymodule/test/MyTest
Defaulting to "console" reporter
Error: Attempt to require unloaded module lib/datastore
    at contextRequire (/home/neek/src/interntest/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:255:12)
    at req (/home/neek/src/interntest/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:30:10)
    at /home/neek/src/interntest/node_modules/nedb/index.js:7:17
    at Function.vm.runInThisContext (/home/neek/src/interntest/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:163:16)
    at /home/neek/src/interntest/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:745:8
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

So after finding `nedb/index.js`, it is now failing to find the relative path referenced within that file, `require('./lib/datastore')`.

Clearly I've got something basic twisted up.  Can someone advise please?

Comment: Have you seen the "Testing Non-AMD Code" section at https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Writing-Tests-with-Intern ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ken, it seems I needed this in my MyTest.js:

```
define([
    'intern!tdd',
    'intern/dojo/node!nedb',
    'intern/dojo/node!nodemailer',
    'intern/chai!assert',
```

apparently because nedb and nodemailer are not AMD, they are CommonJS (?), so you must use the `inter/dojo/node!` plugin to load them in my AMD context.

This produces a working test.

For other people learning this, when creating a very simple AMD module of my own, it can be required as normal.  src/mymodule/Helper.js:

```
define([], function () {

    return {
        doSomething: function () {
            console.log('Helper did something.');
        }
    }
});
```

And the MyTest.js:

```
define([
    'intern!tdd',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/dojo/node!nedb',
    'intern/dojo/node!nodemailer',
    '../Helper'
], function (test, assert, Datastore, nodemailer, Helper) {

    console.log('Great, test module was loaded');

    Helper.doSomething();
});
```

So Helper can be required simply as `mymodule/Helper` or `../Helper` (relative to MyTest.js).